# SED: insert text after the last line?

Tags: sed

This [sed command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20579/117549) inserts a tag to the beginning of a file:

```
sed -i "1s/^/<?php /" file
```

How can I insert something to the *end* of each file with sed?

Comment: `{ cat file; echo 'END OF FILE'; } > newFile `, this works also thanks to sh.*.  (not sed but works and simple)

Comment: a simple `echo "Cool Text" >> file` should also do the trick.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30219386/385273

Comment: Seems the implementation of `sed` differs on macOS. @Danpe echo alternative works nicely.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
sed -i -e '$aTEXTTOEND' filename
```

#### How it works

`$` matches the last line (it's a normal `sed` address; `4aTEXTTOEND` would insert after the fourth line), `a` is the append command, and `TEXTTOEND` is what to append, `filename` is the file where the `TEXTTOEND` will be inserted

Comment: Escape $ as $$ in a Makefile.

Comment: For OS X  `sed -e '$a\NEWLINE\\'`. Replace NEWLINE with an actual new line.

Comment: For Busybox users, the command would be `sed '$aTEXTHERE'`.

Comment: this command is not support a new file. ( zero byte)

Comment: not working on macos. Not even Jorge Bucaran comment: sed: 1: "$a\NEWLINE\\
": extra characters after \ at the end of a command

Comment: In debian 9 it adds a new line instead of adding at the end of the last line.

Comment: Would be nice to write also about the e flag.

Comment: For MacOS sed: `-e $'$a\\\n\\'`

Answer (score 41):

No need to use `sed` in that case. How about

```
echo "<?php" >> file
```

Comment: True enough, but you can guess that the OP's use case is bracketing the file with "`<php `" and "`>`", and quoting selected contents all in one go, so he probably *really* does want a `sed` fragment.

Comment: Also if you'll do this and don't want a newline, use echo -n

Comment: I don't like to guess. Each time I try, I'm wrong.

Comment: Another reason why the accepted answer is more useful is in the case of prepending this with `sudo`, which causes this variation to fail since `echo` is a built-in shell command rather than an executable file found in `$PATH`

Comment: @TonyCesaro: `echo` is a built-in but is *also* a executable file found in `$PATH`

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you want to put the ending php tag to the files, then

```
sed -i '$s/$/\n?>/' file
```

should do the trick

Comment: This works nicely in cases where arbitrary manipulation of the last line of input is desired.  Thanks!

Comment: A decomposed explanation of the command would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 3 years later.  sed -i (edit file in place) '$ (when at the end of the file)  s (sed command for search and replace, searches with regexp like so s/findme/replacewth/) so s/$  ($ regex end of line) /\n?>/  the replacewith is \n?>  so replace the end of the line with (newline ?> which is a closing tag for php

Answer (score 5):

[See your original post for the all-in-one sed command.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20581/117549)

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e "1s/^/<?php /" -e "\$s/\$/ ?>/" {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use sed 'append (a)' command. For example, to append two lines at the end of file:

```
sed -i -e '$a\
foo1 bar1\
foo2 bar2' file
```

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent of your `sed -i '1s/^/<start</' file` would be:

```
sed -i '$s/$/>end>/' file
```

That will add the text `>end>` to the last line (without newlines) of the file. Of course, in this case (as in your example also) it needs that the file contains at least one line (not empty).

Using double quotes (as in the selected answer) is not a good idea as then the shell will try to process each `$` in the string. The command will convert to:

```
sed -i "\$s/\$/>end>/" file
```

Using `a` (append, end) or `i` (insert, start) will also insert a newline, demand different calls in BSD and GNU and still need a non-empty file.

For GNU:

```
$ sed '1i<start<' file
$ sed '$a>end>' file
```

For BSD:

```
$ sed '1i\
<start<' file
$ sed '$a\
>end>' file
```

Or, in shells that allow it (C-string):

```
$ sed $'1i\\\n<start<' file
$ sed $'$a\\\n>end>' file
```

Of course, nothing is simpler than:

```
echo '>end>' >> file
```

which works with empty files as well.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple way to write and make the changes in the contents at a specific line in a file .
If you want to insert anything at a specific line number then below command can be used:

```
sed -i '2i i have started' sheikh.log
```

where `2i` - line number 2 and i stands for inserting . If you have to insert at the last line then use `$` in place of 2 .
i have started - text to be inserted and `sheikh.log` is the filename .

We can also make the changes in the line by using the below command

```
sed -i '2c we have started' sheikh.log
```

`i` is changed to `we` .

Answer (score 0):

## First and Last

I would assume that anyone who searched for how to insert/append text to the beginning/end of a file probably also needs to know how to do the other also.

```
cal |                            \
  gsed -E                        \
       -e     '1i\{'             \
       -e     '1i\  "lines": ['  \
       -e 's/(.*)/    "\1",/'    \
       -e '$s/,$//'              \
       -e     '$a\  ]'           \
       -e     '$a\}'
```

### Explanation

This is `cal` output piped to GNU `sed` (called `gsed` on macOS installed via [brew.sh](https://brew.sh), and simply `sed` on GNU installations) with extended RegEx (`-E`) and 6 "scripts" applied (`-e`) and line breaks escaped with `\` for readability.

- Scripts 1 & 2 use `1i\` to "at line 1, insert".
- Scripts 5 & 6 use `$a\` to "at line <last>, append". I vertically aligned the text outputs to make the code represent what is expected in the result.
- Scripts 3 & 4 do substitutions (the latter applying only to "line <last>").

The result is converting command output to valid JSON.

#### Output

```
{
  "lines": [
    "    October 2019      ",
    "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  ",
    "       1  2  3  4  5  ",
    " 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  ",
    "13 14 15 16 17 18 19  ",
    "20 21 22 23 24 25 26  ",
    "27 28 29 30 31        ",
    "                      "
  ]
}
```

Comment: While I haven't voted on your question, note that we already have several answers, including an accepted one, that demonstrate the desired result.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The Stack Exchange community is not a forum. Its purpose extends beyond helping the OP get unblocked. The goal is to seed the global knowledge base with many options that seekers can stumble upon when searching for answers. The reason I titled my answer is to help users recognize the utility of this answer before they even click the Google result.