# How can I prepend a tag to the beginning of several files?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to add PHP tags surrounding a file. It's easy to append them using

```
find . -exec echo "?>" >> '{}' \;
```

but how can I *prepend* the tag `<?php`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
sed -i "1s/^/<?php /" file
```

(The `-i` is for in-place edit.)

More portable version:

```
ed file <<!
1s/^/<?php /
wq
!
```

Comment: nifty - that's a bit easier than what I was about to describe :)

Comment: I need to add the extension to the -i argument here.  Are you using sed or GNU sed?

Comment: Richard: The one I'm using claims to be GNU `sed`, and it allows adding a backup suffix.

Comment: I'm using BSD sed, and it allows in place editing, but I need to give it an extension. i.e.  'sed -i .bak "PATTERN" file'

Comment: `-i` is not portable, the syntax differs between implementations, and it breaks symlinks. You'd be better off using an application that is actually designed to edit files.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with a perl one-liner:

```
perl -0777 -p -i -e "s/^/hey /g" testfile
```

The `-0777` forces file-slurping mode, so the entire file is read as one line. `-p` enables looping. `-i` enables in-place editing of the file. `^` indicates the beginning of a line.

```
$ cp testfile1 testfile; perl -0777 -p -i -e "s/^/hey /g" testfile; diff testfile testfile1
1c1
< hey asdf
---
> asdf
```

**Update:** As indicated in the comments, you can choose to auto-generate a backup by using `-i.bak` instead of `-i`. This provides additional safety in case of errors in your command. The argument to `-i`  becomes the suffix of the backup.

When updating a bunch of files, you could run the command with `-i.backup${RANDOM}`, check that all files updated correctly, then remove all files with that extension.

Comment: "The value 0777 will cause Perl to slurp files whole because
there is no legal byte with that value" see http://sial.org/howto/perl/one-liner/#s3.5

Comment: If you recommend use of the `-i` flag without a suffix, please warn readers that this means *you get no backup*. For a few characters more (`-i.bak`), you get a backup in case your one-liner includes a typo. A fairly simple typo (say, forgetting the `-p` flag) can ruin your whole day otherwise.

Comment: @Telemachus - Agreed. Updated.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an `AWK` filter like this,

```
awk '{if(NR==1) printf "%s%s","PREFIX",$0; else print $0}' testfile > newfile
```

Where `PREFIX` is your php prefix string.

Answer (score 5):

I can't leave a comment yet, but to do it all in one step:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i -e "1s/^/<?php /" -e "\$s/\$/ ?>/" {} \;
```

Comment: Love it, saved me hours.

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is for editing streams  -- a file is not a stream. Use a program that is meant for this purpose, like`ed` or `ex`. The `-i` option to `sed` is not only not portable, it will also break any symlinks you may encounter, since it essentially deletes it and recreates it, which is pointless.

```
for file in foo bar baz; do
    ed -s "${file}" << EOF
0a
<?php 
.
w
EOF
done
```

Comment: What you presented is a basic way to edit a single file. This does not seem to answer the problem - the question is about modifying a number of files (though it may not be obvious at first glance). If you know how to use `ed` for that purpose, show this in your answer.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz - Since grawity demonstrated the same method of editing a single file (that was accepted), I thought it was appropriate to the answer. Either way, I put it in a for loop, which should ease your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what you wrote for adding something to the end of every file in the directory (in `bash`):

```
for FNAME in *
do
    echo "?>" >> $FNAME
done
```

though I do like your `find` one-liner :)

Comment: `$FNAME` should be `$fname` -- by convention, we capitalize environment variables (PAGER, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables (BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...). All other variable names should contain at least one lowercase letter. This convention avoids accidentally overriding environmental and internal variables.

Comment: @Chris Down  - the convention I have seen my entire career has varied by setting: lowercase, upper case, and camelcase :)

Comment: Camelcase and lowercase are fine. Either way, variables that are not environment variables should not be in full uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

There is the simple way

```
echo "startstr$(cat filename)endstring" > filename.new
```

Comment: This will break with trailing newlines.

Comment: @ChrisDown trailing newlines in the file?