# How to prepend a license header recursively for all .h and .cpp files in a directory

Tags: text-processing, shell-script

I'm trying to add a license header to all header files and source files in a project directory using a for loop. This is not working, is there any other approach using `sed`?

Comment: Very similar case: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/unix-add-a-tag-to-the-beginning-of-each-file

Comment: Related (has some Python code examples): [language agnostic - Tool for adding license headers to source files? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151677/tool-for-adding-license-headers-to-source-files)

Answer (score 15):

```
shopt -s globstar

for f in **/*.cpp; do
  cat header_file "$f" > "$f.new"  &&  mv "$f.new" "$f"
done
```

Notes:

- This assumes that you have full (read+write+execute) access
  to the directory tree.
- All `.cpp` files will be re-created, owned by you and with default permissions. 
  Hard links (if any) will be broken.

Comment: It should be mentioned that you need to turn on `globstar` in bash for this to work.

Comment: And that you need bash > 4.0 (e.g., Mac OS X and RedHat 5 are still on 3.X)

Answer (score 14):

This is more or less just an extended commentary on *Daniel Serodio'`* answer. I started writitng it as a comment, but it quickly grew too large...

For a bash glob to be recursive, it requires `shopt -s globstar`. You must enable globstar, otherwise `**` doesn't work. The globstar shell option was introduced to version 4 of bash.

To avoid processing a directory such as `my.cpp/`, use the test `[[ -f $f ]]`... When the test is in double square-brackets, variables don't need to be double quoted.

You can also consider the possibility of there being no matching files by using `shopt -s nullglob`, which allows patterns which match no files to expand to a null string, rather than themselves.

To handle multiple patterns, you can chain the glob patterns: `**/*.cpp  **/*.h`, but perhaps preferrably, when the shell option *extglob* is *on* via `shopt -s extglob`, you can use such constructs such as `**/*.@(cpp|h)` which avoids multiple passes over the file system; once for each pattern.

If you want `.files` to be included, use `.*.cpp` etc, or use `shopt -s dotglob`

To safely handle modifying a file which is being piped, use `sponge` from package `moreutils` (it saves you the need to create your own temp file)

---

```
printf "// The License\n\n" > /tmp/$USER-license

shopt -s globstar nullglob extglob
for f in **/*.@(cpp|h) ;do
  [[ -f $f ]] && cat "/tmp/$USER-license" "$f" | sponge "$f"
done
```

Comment: Much more complete and informative answer than the other one, +1

Comment: +1, but `[[` can gracefully handle a null `$f`.

Comment: @enzotib. thanks. I'm not sure were I got that idea from. It must have been from how the single square-bracket works (doesn't)... eg `unset x; [ -f $x ] && echo exists`  reports "exists" ... (fixed)

Comment: Since version 4 of bash is not mainstream yet I would substitute the `**/*.@(cpp|h)` with `$( find . -name "*.h" -name "*.cpp")`

Answer (score 3):

Thank you @fred, @maxmackie, @enzotib.

Can you please check the procedure I have followed.

```
#!/bin/sh
# script to copy the headers to all the source files and header files
for f in *.cpp; do
  if (grep Copyright $f);then 
    echo "No need to copy the License Header to $f"
  else
    cat license.txt $f > $f.new
    mv $f.new $f
    echo "License Header copied to $f"
  fi 
done
```

otherwise the license header will be copied to multiple number of times.

Please suggest me a pattern to go through all the headers and sources in project directory and subdirectories.

I could not understand fully what @fred has suggested.

Comment: In general, your code looks okay. I would be more specific about identifying the exact location of "Copyright", eg. specify the line number and position on that line. You can prevent sed reading the entire file by quitting on the line where you expect to find "Copyright"... eg.  `targln=2; findln=$(sed -rne $targln'{\|// Copyright|=;q}' "$f"); if ((findln==targln));then` ... but, of course, above and beyond everything else, thoroughly test it first... PS. It is par for the course here at *Unix & Linux* to post such *extras* in your original question, *not* as an answer...

Comment: Some advices: remove parentheses around `grep`, add `-q` option to `grep`. Always add double quotes around `$f`.

Comment: Quotes are vital, otherwise you will be likely bitten by word splitting. As a basic rule, quote every expansion unless you know that word splitting or other interpretation will not be performed by the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `ex` or `ed` if you prefer (you should not do this with `sed` as you requested, `sed` is designed to edit streams, `-i` is a bad idea for a variety of reasons):

```
shopt -s globstar

for _file in **/*.@(cpp|h); do
    ed -s "${_file}" << EOF
0a
/* This file is licensed under the foo license.
   All copyright strictly enforced by the copyright monster. */
.
w
EOF
    done
```

Comment: Why is `sed -i` a bad idea?

Comment: @DanielSerodio By default, `sed -i` breaks symlinks and hardlinks, resulting in unexpected behaviour. At best it is non-intuitive, at worse it is actively harmful.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `find . -name '*.[m|h]'` # or whatever other pattern...
do
  echo $i
  if ! grep -q Copyright $i
  then
    cat copyright.txt $i >$i.new && mv $i.new $i
  fi
done
enter code here
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `header_file` with desired contents:

```
find -name '*.cpp' -exec bash -c 'cat header_file \{} > \{}.new; mv \{}.new  \{}' \;
find -name '*.h' -exec bash -c 'cat header_file \{} > \{}.new; mv \{}.new  \{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gerhard Gappmeier's blog - Howto recursively replace file headers of source files](https://gergap.wordpress.com/2009/06/03/howto-recursively-replace-file-headers-of-source-files/)

The blog post has attached a `tar.gz` file, containing the files needed.

It has a `header.template` file, where you can write a custom comment, it can span multiple lines.

It has an `remove_header.awk` script that replaces existing headers with the new header.

In order to run it:

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec ~/rh/replace_header.sh {} \;
```