# Inserting text at the beginning of a file with sed via the terminal in Linux

Tags: text-processing, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prepend a tag to the beginning of several files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20577/how-can-i-prepend-a-tag-to-the-beginning-of-several-files)

How do I insert text at the beginning of a file via terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sed` is for editing streams  -- a file is not a stream. Use a program that is meant for this purpose, like`ed` or `ex`. The `-i` option to `sed` is not only not portable, it will also break any symlinks to your file, since it essentially deletes it and recreates it, which is pointless.

```
ed -s file << EOF
0a
some text
you want to insert
goes here
.
w
EOF
```

Comment: A wonderful demonstration of why 'ed' simply refuses to die :)

Comment: This doesn't break the symbolic link, `echo abc>f; ln -s f fln; sed -ie "s/abc/XXX/" f` ... GNU sed 4.2.1

Comment: @fred You misunderstand what I'm saying. Try using `-i` on the symlink.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now

Comment: re. `sed -i` ... a very good point. When it acts on a symlink, eg. `fln`, the end result is two "normal" files! The original is unchanged, and the symlink simply disappears and is replaced by a modified "normal" file of the same name. Not a good thing!  ... I then tested `sed -e '...' fln | sponge fln`  ... *sponge* handled the symlink correctly ... @Chris Down, Thanks for heads-up on this issue...

Answer (score 5):

Specify a line range in input file which is restricted to first line, then replace beginning of line with text to add and redirect o/p to a new file

```
cat f1
one

sed '1,1 s/^/abcdef\n/' < f1 >f2

cat f2
abcdef
one
```

Comment: nice answer abc. See my own one for a modification of yours

Answer (score 2):

+1 for abc's answer because I find his nice sed expression.

However Regis doesn't want two files, he wants to *insert* text in his file; so I have adapted abc's answer:

```
hmontoliu@ulises:/tmp$ cat >  f1 
one
^C
hmontoliu@ulises:/tmp$ sed -i '1 s/^/foobar\n/' f1
hmontoliu@ulises:/tmp$ cat f1
foobar
one
```