# Adding a TeX macro to the beginning of a file using sed (why doesn't my method work?)

Tags: text-processing, sed

I need to add a line to the beginning of a file. The line in question is

```
\def\submit{}
```

I've got a semi-working solution using `sed`. I don't know `sed`, but got it from somewhere on the net, but it doesn't work quite right, because it inserts an unwanted space at the beginning of the line. While this doesn't really matter, I figure I might as well do this right.

```
sed -i '1i\ \\\def\\\submit{}' 'dirname/filename'
```

It seems from my reading that all those extra backslashes are required to escape the shell. Other solutions are also welcome, but I'd like a comparably compact one liner if possible. Thanks.

This question, [Inserting text at the beginning of a file with sed via the terminal in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/inserting-text-at-the-beginning-of-a-file-with-sed-via-the-terminal-in-linux) is similar, but doesn't help me debug my expression.

EDIT: I've accepted @Jonathan's answer, because it explains what was wrong with my previous approach. However, I've also added an answer.

Comment: Interesting edit. Is there a way to keep the question closed but modify the duplicate it points to?

Comment: @rahmu Don't see how. The duplicate is not really a duplicate imo.

Comment: Actually, if you want to use `1i` you need GNU `sed`. And unless you want a leading space on the first line, the `sed` command should be: `1i\\\def\\submit{}`. The first backslash needs to be tripled because the first backslash *character* is actually part of the command name, which is `i\ `.

Comment: @peterph This does not work for me - I tried `sed -i '1i\\\def\\submit{}\'   'dir1/foo'`. Feel free to submit your own solution. I got `\\def\\submit{}`.

Comment: Well, I suggested `1i\\\def\\submit{}`, you tried `1i\\\def\\submit{}\ ` - don't be surprised you got different result.

Comment: @peterph: Yes, sorry about that. Actually, what you suggest is the same as Jonathan's suggestion below. Except that you have one less slash before the `submit`, which however, doesn't make any difference to the result - both versions work. I guess I should stop cargo-culting and understand what sed actually does.

Comment: Escaping backslashes is usually a tricky thing. Anyway, I've summarized my findings in a new answer (editing any existing one didn't seem appropriate in this case) - it might clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to sed right now, so I'm not entirely sure this is correct, but I think you just need to remove the first backslash and the space following it.

```
sed -i '1i\\\def\\\submit{}' 'dirname/filename'
```

Try it and see if that works.

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is for editing streams  -- a file is not a stream. Use a program that is meant for this purpose, like`ed` or `ex`. The `-i` option to `sed` is not only not portable, it will also break any symlinks to your file, since it essentially deletes it and recreates it, which is pointless.

```
ed -s [file] << EOF
0a
\\def\\submit{}
.
w
EOF
```

Comment: [jw013](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9537/jw013) [suggests](http://unix.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/784) that you mean hard links, not symlinks

Comment: @Michael -- I don't. Try creating a file, then creating a symlink to that file, then passing the symlink as the file for `sed -i` to operate on.

Comment: @ChrisDown Just saw this again.  You are indeed correct about `-i` removing symlinks, although GNU `sed` provides the `--follow-symlinks` option for that case.  Of course all of this is rendered moot by the more important point that `sed -i` is non-portable and should be avoided anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get a working version of this by using [an answer to: "How can I prepend a tag to the beginning of several files?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20579/4671).

I was not previously aware of this question. The solution is:

```
sed -i '1s/^/\\\def\\\submit{}\n/' 'dirname/filename'
```

BTW, I think: "How can I prepend a tag to the beginning of several files?" would be a better question to reference than the: "Inserting text at the beginning of a file with sed via the terminal in Linux" which this question was linked to. It has a lot more answers.

Answer (score 0):

First: the escaping backslashes are not because of the shell - the string is single quoted. Rather it is because of `sed` itself.

Secondly: Chris Down's answer has some merit - don't use hammer instead of screwdriver. On the other hand, portability and symlinks are not always an issue, if that is the case, both

```
sed '1i\\\def\\submit{}'
```

and

```
sed '1i\\def\submit{}\'
```

Should do what you need. I wasn't able to find out why the trailing backslash in the latter form turns off escaping in the string, but it seems to work like that, at least in the GNU `sed` when the commands are put on a command line. When used in a script, only the first form seems to work (because trailing backslash is used to denote end of line which is followed by another one):

```
#!/bin/sed -f 
1i\
\\def\\submit{}
```