# prepend the text file output to other file

Tags: shell, sed, command

I want to prepend the data of a file (`random.txt`) into another set of files (`real.txt`) in a folder.

Take the following example:

```
$ cat random
some text

$ cat real.txt
sample text
```

If I run the following command:

```
$ sed i.old '1s;^;some text\n;' real.txt

$ cat real.txt
some text

sample text
```

This command prepends the text of file `random` into file `real.txt`, but the content of `random` is not fixed. Is it possible to redirect the content of the `random` into `real.txt`?

I tried the following command:

```
$ sed -i.old "1s;^;$(cat random)\n;" real.txt

$ cat real.txt
```

Which gives the output:

```
some text
sample text
```

The problem occurs when i my random fil gets a txt starting with "/*". It shows following error:

```
$ cat real.txt
/*new text
 new line*/
$sed -i.old "1s;^;$(cat random)\n;" real.txt
 sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what your goal is. Can you show the actual file and the change you expect? Edit your question to include this.

Comment: changed it a little. Hope it is more clear now

Comment: What I'm getting here is you're trying to do `cat random real.txt`? And just have the text from `random` before `real.txt`?

Comment: correct. but i get following error when i try with cat: 
cat random real.txt > real.txt
cat: real.txt: input file is output file

Comment: PIggy backing off of your conversation with @Panki, you can just do `cat random real.txt > tmp` followed by `mv tmp real.txt`. You cannot pipe into an output file when it is also the input of the `cat` command.

Comment: Specifically, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56977/135943

Comment: @DTdev Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically addressing the question of why your `sed` syntax doesn't work, process substitution will not occur inside single quotes.

This syntax works for me:

```
sed -i.old "1s;^;$(cat random)\\
;" filename
```

If you're using GNU `sed`, this will work also:

```
sed -i.old "1s;^;$(cat random)\n;" filename
```

Addressing your edit, and focusing on GNU `sed`, two solutions come to mind:

1) avoid syntax inside `random` which bothers `sed`.  In your specific case, that is the use of a literal newline inside the file.

Instead of:

```
/* line1 
   line2 */
```

Encode the newline (at the end of line 1) as `\n`:

```
/* line1\n   line2 */
```

The final newline in `random` (at the end of line 2) is **already** encoded as `\n` in the `sed` command line.

2) abandon in-place editing with `sed` and use a "`cat`-and-`mv`" approach:

```
for f in filename; do
    mv $f $f.old
    cat random $f.old > $f
done
```

Comment: ok. i got that it works, but if the text of my random contains "/*" i get following error: 
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unterminated `s' command

Comment: @DTdev Then you need to go back and [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/543911/edit) to show your actual use case.  It's possible `sed` might not be the correct tool for your job.