# SED and PDSH: adding a line to a file on a slave node in a cluster

Tags: sed, cluster, pdsh

I am trying to add a new line containing `GATEWAY=10.0.10.1` to the `/etc/sysconfig/network` file on each of 32 slave nodes in a cluster.
I read this [post on how to insert a line with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/sed-insert-something-to-the-last-line).

This works for me to add a line to a local file:

```
sed -i.bak -e "\$aGATEWAY=10.0.10.1" test/test1
```

This works for me viewing a file on node 32:

```
pdsh -w n032 cat test/test1
```

**This fails** for me trying to add a line to a file on node 32:

```
pdsh -w n032 sed -i.bak -e "\$aGATEWAY=10.0.10.1" test/test1
```

With this error:

```
n032: sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
pdsh@admin: n032: ssh exited with exit code 1
```

I own the file that I'm trying to change:

```
pdsh -w n032 ls -al test/test1
```

The above command shows that I own it and have read and write (`rw`) permissions.

Why does it fail?

Comment: Welcome on unix.stackexchange. The error is not referred to permission to write but on `sed`. Probably you have to escape in a different way the expression "\$aGATEWAY=10.0.10.1" that should be expanded by your local shell.

Comment: @Hastur - `"\$aGATEWAY=10.0.10.1"` is escaped perfectly well as far as I can tell. What do you mean?

Comment: @mikeserv I'afraid that the remote node will see the command so `sed -i.bak -e =10.0.10.1 test/test1`...

Comment: Oh - I think you're right @Hastur. Probably something like `ssh "sed ... -e "\$a...""` - anyway you're definitely right about the error - nothing to do with the file.

Comment: @mikeserv It should be enough to add single quote `'` as `ssh sed -e '"\$a..."'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok try with this command line:

```
pdsh -w n032  sed -i.bak -e '"\$aGATEWAY=10.0.10.1"' test/test1;
```

With `ssh` it works. If it works locally (on the nodes) the simple command, it should work this line too.

When you try without quote `'`, the shell locally (on the current shell on entry computer) will expand and transform for the node the line in:

```
sed -i.bak -e =10.0.10.1 test/test1
```

and you will read that error.

Maybe you can find interesting e.g. [this chapter](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php) or [this other](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).