# Sed Replace a pattern between a pattern and the end of file

Tags: text-processing, sed

From [SED: insert text after the last line? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26639/220462), I learnt that `$` if used outside the substitution in sed represents the end of file. This I have tried to use in the follwing to replace all occurences of `abc` occuring after `# Start` and till end of the file by `123`

Code:

```
file=Data.txt
Initial="# Start";
Final='\$'
orig="abc";
new="123"; 
sed -i -r -e "\!${Initial}!,\!${Final}!{s!${orig}!${new}!g}" ${file} ;
```

Data.txt

```
# Start

abc
abc

$

abc
abc
```

Output:

```
# Start

123
123

$

abc
abc
```

Expected Output:

```
# Start

123
123

$

123
123
```

What am I missing? **i.e. How to tell to sed that `$` means end of the file?**

---

Note: I am escaping `$`, as I am using double quotes in the sed expression (for safer variable expansion). I hope this is correct. Can you comment on this?

Comment: You're telling `sed` to substitute in a range that starts with a line that matches `# Start` and ends with a line that matches `$` and that's exactly what it does...

Comment: But how to tell that `$` means end of the file? (as in the referred link). [SED: insert text after the last line? - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26639/220462)

Comment: _"I learnt that `$` if used outside the substitution in sed represents the end of file"_ ... Well, not quite, apparently... What's stopping you from using `$` ? And btw, of all delimiters that could be used, `!` is probably the worst choice...

Comment: @don_crissti Could you please give an example of how to use `$` in above example to mean end of file? Also if possible, please give a suitable delimiter that you think is usually good in most of the cases. I used `!` as it is rarely used symbol.

Comment: If you go back to the page you linked to you'll see at least two examples of proper usage of `$` as an address. **Ignore the accepted answer there** which needlessly complicates things by double quoting and escaping the `$`.

Comment: @don_crissti I am clear with the idea that I am escaping `$` as I am using double quotes in the sed expression (for safer variable expansion). So, I used the exact thing here. Isn't it? Could you please find the flaw with my example?

Comment: No, you _don't need_ to escape the `$` in the RHS of that assignment. As to your problem, I recommend reading the manual if you really want to learn something... You'll find out that `$` is a special address that designates the last line _but not if you use it as a pattern_...

Comment: Imho, you are needlessly making a simple pbm complex by bringing in the vagaries of quoting into play. For understanding, you need to start simple. Once get a handle then add complexity nd see where it goes.

Comment: @RakeshSharma Could you please simplify this that works? I am asking you because I already tried this but could not do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works: (Note: `${Final}` instead of `/${Final}/` )

```
file=Data.txt
Initial="# Start";
orig="abc";
new="123"; 
Final='$' # Line Number
sed -r -e "/${Initial}/,${Final}s/${orig}/${new}/g" ${file}
```

Comment: `-r` not needed as no extended regular expression features are used.