# Ways to append text to a file

Tags: shell-script, shell

I always do this to append text to a file

```bsh
echo "text text text ..." >> file
# or
printf "%s\n" "text text text ..." >> file
```

I wonder if there are more ways to achieve the same, more elegant or unusual way.

Comment: As I already said, it's not only that. `echo "a\nb"` will print something different than `printf "%s\n" "a\nb"`, in ~all the shells but bash. You cannot assume that the two are similar.

Comment: Note that you can group commands together `(a ; b ; c) >> file`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I quite like this one, where I can set up a log file at the top of a script and write to it throughout without needing either a global variable or to remember to change all occurrences of a filename:

```
exec 3>> /tmp/somefile.log
...

echo "This is a log message" >&3
echo "This goes to stdout"
echo "This is written to stderr" >&2
```

The `exec 3>dest` construct opens the file `dest` for writing (use `>>` for appending, `<` for reading - just as usual) and attaches it to file descriptor #3. You then get descriptor #1 for *stdout*, #2 for *stderr*, and this new #3 for the file `dest`.

You can join *stderr* to *stdout* for the duration of a script with a construct such as `exec 2>&1` - there are lots of powerful possibilities. The documentation (`man bash`) has this to say about it:

> **`exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`** If `command` is specified, it replaces the shell. [...] *If `command` is not specified, any redirections take effect in the current shell [...].*

Answer (score 14):

Here are few other ways to append text to a file.

1. Using tee

   ```bsh
   tee -a file <<< "text text text ..."
   ```
2. Using awk

   ```bsh
   awk 'BEGIN{ printf "text text text ..." >> "file" }'
   ```
3. Using sed

   ```bsh
   sed -i '$a text text text ...' file
   sed -i -e "\$atext text text ..." file
   ```

Sources:

- [How to Append to End of a File in
  Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/append-to-end-of-file-in-linux/)
- [SED: insert text after the last line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/sed-insert-text-after-the-last-line)

Comment: sed -i does not so much append as overwrite with an extended version.  Normally not much of an issue, but it can be if the file is sparse, linked, or actively being read.

Answer (score 11):

Using a [`here-document`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) approach:

```
cat <<EOF >> file
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EOF
```

Tests:

```
$ cat file
aaaa
bbbb

$ cat <<EOF >> file
> foo
> bar
> baz
> EOF

$ cat file
aaaa
bbbb
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Why downvote? This is a valid answer tho.

Comment: @annahri See updated answer with tests.

Comment: This is very, very useful in scripts.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

See [dd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html) man page:

```
dd conv=notrunc oflags=append bs=4096 if=myNewData of=myOldFile
```

Comment: This is creative, but can you use a line of string instead of an input file?

Comment: @annahri yes certainly, `dd conv=notruct oflag=append of=destination <<<'Some string of text'`

Comment: @roaima that's shell dependent though. Not all shells support the `<<<` herestring construct. I have no idea what `dd` would do in those cases, would it be safe?

Comment: @terdon I believe that the here-string construct is like feeding `dd` from any other file descriptor (but I've not checked the source). On that assumption, I would expect `dd` to be as safe as with any other similar invocation. `echo 'Some string of text or printf if you prefer' | dd conv=notrunc oflag=append of=destination`, etc.

Comment: @roaima sure, with shells that support `<<<`, it should be perfectly safe. I just wonder what happens with shells that don't. Will `dd` simply get no input and, if so, not write anything? Will it write an empty string? Or a NULL? I guess it would do nothing, but I was just idly wondering since I don't know.

Comment: @annahri. My bad: I scrolled down under "Each CONV symbol may be:" on the man page, and missed the bit where the list changes to "Each FLAG symbol may be:".

Comment: I tested dd with <<< in dash. It throws "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" with status 2, so dd itself is not even invoked.

Comment: `dash` and other POSIX shells does not have a `herestring` only a `heredoc` so it stands to reason that if `dd` accepts input from `stdin` it should work with a `heredoc` on POSIX shells, see https://paste.opensuse.org/view/raw/14083760

Comment: The shell performs redirection regardless if you have it in the beginning,middle,last part of the code/script before any commands/expansion gets executed, in this case the herestring `<<<`

Comment: @jetchisel. In your example containing >>outputfile, I don't see that dd needs either the notrunc or append options. It (dd) just inherits a stream already opened in append mode, and it does not even know the filename.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant indeed, i stand corected. `dd  <<'EOF' >> file`  `literal newlinehere`  'text here`  `EOF` is enough.

Comment: @jetchisel. Actually, showing these options is probably a good idea, even if not required here. They cause no harm. They show intent. They protect functionality if somebody changes to of=myFile without due care. dd is obscure in places, so I never use short-form options.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Unix file editors. Both `GNU` and `BSD` version.

Using `ed(1)` with `printf`

```
printf '%s\n' '$a' 'foo bar baz' . w | ed -s file.txt
```

The bash specific but more cryptic syntax using the `$' '` shell quoting and a `herestring`

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'$a\nfoo bar baz\n.\nw'
```

Using `ex(1)` with `printf`

```
printf '%s\n' '$a' 'foo bar baz' . x | ex -s file.txt
```

The bash specific but more cryptic syntax `$' '` shell quoting and a `herestring`

```
ex -s file.txt <<< $'$a\nfoo bar baz\n.\nx'
```

Comment: ed, ex, and other text editors do not so much append as overwrite with an extended version.  Normally not much of an issue, but it can be if the file is sparse, linked, or actively being read.

Comment: @DavidG. Thank you for that wonderful comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat >> file
first line
second line
...
last line
```

Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the last line then <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>.

Comment: I often use this now to copy-paste things into a file quickly.